# Finite element method - master element

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

What is supposed to be a *quadratic master element with 3 degrees of freedom*?

I think I have to consider a 3D case, with x,y,z directions...is it?
And I think it is quadratic because I have to go until degree 2 of Lagrange interpolation.

Or is it something different?

Comment: In the 1D case, a degree-(at most)-$2$ element would have 3 dofs: Two boundary nodes and one internal node, each counted with one dof.

Comment: @ccorn, so, in 1D case, how many variables does shape functions have? 1? or 3?